# Access values in existing properties

Tags: sass

I am using this function to convert px to em vals.

```
@function em($px, $base: $base-font-size)
    @return ($px / $base) * 1em
```

Since ems require the parent/element font-size is there a way in sass that I could access the current element font-size property.

Eg.

```
h1
    font-size: em(54px)
    margin-top: em(92px, the_above_font_size)
```

This way if I change the element font-sze I won't have to change the passed in param values as well. I am new to SASS, please tell me if this is possible or any other alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this!?

```
h1
    $fontsize = em(54px);
    font-size: $fontsize;
    margin-top: em(92px, $fontsize);
```

Comment: This will still cause problems if I have the same font size for h1,h3 and try to set different margins to each element. $fontsize will be out of scope. Even though its's possible to declare this gloablly, it would difficult to change later-on. Seems like there is no other solution at the moment right??